# Wordfilter that doesn't replace already filtered content

Tags: php

I have *wordfilter* table in MySQL, and I use PHP to get all rows from it and replace them inside string.

```
$string = "test string";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM wordfilter;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $string = str_replace($row['search'], $row['replace'], $string);
}
```

It will work like this:

```
Iteration number: (row from table) - result string
0: "tt string e"
1: ("tt", "<b>test</b>") - "<b>test</b> string e"
2: ("e", "f") - "<b>tfst</b> string f"
etc.
```

I want it to have this result `"<b>test</b> string f"` (the "e" doesn't replace with "f" in `<b>test</b>`, because it wasn't present in input string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an array of your search-replace pairs like so:

```
$reps = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $reps[$row['search']] = $row['replace'];
```

Then use the magic of [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr);

```
$string = strtr($string,$reps);
```